# Is there any way to know which script call a particular script in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how scripts are getting called. In particular I want to know if there is a method to trace the calling of the scripts. For example: I have a script loaded `X.js` which is loaded because `Y.js` called it which in turn is loaded because `Z.js` called it. And Z.js is in the web page's `head` tag. My question is if I have breakpoint on `X.js` is there any way to who called it?

Comment: What do you mean "Y.js called it" ? A script doesn't "call" another one.

Comment: You can load a js from another js

Comment: @Huangism Yes but there are so many ways to do this, usually asynchronously, that the question is too vague to make sense to me.

Comment: Are you using a JavaScript library, for instance requirejs?

Comment: Do you want the call stack, or the resource that loaded the script?

Comment: Aren't all dynamically created scripts loaded asynchronously?

Comment: @dystroy - By "call" I mean "reference'. That is Y.js has some line which refers to X.js so the browser downloads X.js

Comment: What you mean is that you want to build a dependency graph for your source files ?

Comment: @PervySage Either I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, or you're misunderstanding how browsers work. In order for one script to call a function or reference a variable defined in another script, both must have been loaded already.

Comment: @dystroy Yes I agree the fact the question is very vague

Comment: @dystroy - Yes that would be great! It would tell me what scripts refer to what other scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Most debuggers that are built into browsers will give you a stacktrace at any breakpoint.

You can see the file name of the script and the line number and click on them to jump to that code in the debugger.

This example is from Chrome:

[image: Debugger from Chrome]

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about scripts, not function calls.

Comment: @dystroy — Functions are defined by scripts. The debugger shows the file name of the script that defines it.

Comment: If you call a function in another script, not if you require the loading of the script. But I'm not really sure of what's the question, so maybe you answer it.